# Internet Connection Continuously Restart

Tags: networking, network-manager

My internet connection couldn't stay stable. It restarts almost every minute.

I am connect with cable network and my Ubuntu machine reset its internet connection almost severel second. When I look my syslog I read this logs:

My syslog output:

```
May 28 05:17:12 main systemd-networkd[354]: enp4s0: Lost carrier
May 28 05:17:12 main kernel: [  821.785302] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
May 28 05:17:12 main systemd-timesyncd[677]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 28 05:17:12 main avahi-daemon[761]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.2.222 on enp4s0.
May 28 05:17:12 main avahi-daemon[761]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.222.
May 28 05:17:12 main avahi-daemon[761]: Interface enp4s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 28 05:17:12 main avahi-daemon[761]: Withdrawing address record for fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.
May 28 05:17:12 main avahi-daemon[761]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 28 05:17:12 main avahi-daemon[761]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 28 05:17:12 main avahi-daemon[761]: Registering new address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.*.
May 28 05:17:12 main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1318]: [2239:2296:0528/081712.809053:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(416)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
May 28 05:17:15 main systemd-networkd[354]: enp4s0: Gained carrier
May 28 05:17:15 main kernel: [  824.777361] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link up
May 28 05:17:15 main NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1527484635.2960] device (enp4s0): carrier: link connected
May 28 05:17:15 main avahi-daemon[761]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.222.
May 28 05:17:15 main avahi-daemon[761]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 28 05:17:15 main avahi-daemon[761]: Registering new address record for 192.168.2.222 on enp4s0.IPv4.
May 28 05:17:15 main systemd-networkd[354]: enp4s0: Configured
May 28 05:17:16 main avahi-daemon[761]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 28 05:17:16 main avahi-daemon[761]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 28 05:17:16 main avahi-daemon[761]: Registering new address record for fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.*.
May 28 05:17:16 main avahi-daemon[761]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.
May 28 05:17:36 main kernel: [  845.721238] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
May 28 05:17:36 main systemd-networkd[354]: enp4s0: Lost carrier
May 28 05:17:36 main avahi-daemon[761]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.2.222 on enp4s0.
May 28 05:17:36 main avahi-daemon[761]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.222.
May 28 05:17:36 main avahi-daemon[761]: Interface enp4s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 28 05:17:36 main systemd-timesyncd[677]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 28 05:17:36 main avahi-daemon[761]: Withdrawing address record for fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.
May 28 05:17:36 main avahi-daemon[761]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 28 05:17:36 main avahi-daemon[761]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 28 05:17:36 main avahi-daemon[761]: Registering new address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.*.
May 28 05:17:38 main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1318]: [2239:2296:0528/081738.242003:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(416)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
May 28 05:17:39 main systemd-networkd[354]: enp4s0: Gained carrier
May 28 05:17:39 main NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1527484659.2009] device (enp4s0): carrier: link connected
May 28 05:17:39 main kernel: [  848.685225] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link up
May 28 05:17:39 main avahi-daemon[761]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.222.
May 28 05:17:39 main avahi-daemon[761]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 28 05:17:39 main avahi-daemon[761]: Registering new address record for 192.168.2.222 on enp4s0.IPv4.
May 28 05:17:39 main systemd-networkd[354]: enp4s0: Configured
May 28 05:17:41 main avahi-daemon[761]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 28 05:17:41 main avahi-daemon[761]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 28 05:17:41 main avahi-daemon[761]: Registering new address record for fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.*.
May 28 05:17:41 main avahi-daemon[761]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.
```

My Inxi Output:

```
System:    Host: main.u3g Kernel: 4.15.0-22-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0 Desktop: i3 4.14.1
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop System: MSI product: MS-7693 v: 2.0 serial: N/A
           Mobo: MSI model: 970A-G46 (MS-7693) v: 2.0 serial: N/A
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: V2.8 date: 01/08/2016
Battery    hidpp__0: charge: N/A condition: NA/NA Wh model: Logitech Wireless Keyboard K360 status: Discharging
CPU:       8 core AMD FX-8320 Eight-Core (-MCP-) arch: Bulldozer rev.0 cache: 16384 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm) bmips: 56003
           clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 1399 MHz 2: 1396 MHz 3: 1580 MHz 4: 1627 MHz 5: 1398 MHz 6: 1397 MHz
           7: 1470 MHz 8: 1403 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850 / R7 265 / R9 270 1024SP]
           bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: amdgpu
           Resolution: 1280x800@60.16hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series version: 4.6.13527 18.20.2.15 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:14.2
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-22-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
           IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1861.4GB (5.0% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD5001AALS size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD10EZEX size: 1000.2GB
           ID-3: /dev/sdc model: KINGSTON_SHFS37A size: 240.1GB
           ID-4: /dev/sdd model: INTEL_SSDSC2CT12 size: 120.0GB
           ID-5: USB /dev/sde model: Cruzer_Micro size: 1.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 59G used: 7.1G (13%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc1
           ID-2: /home size: 161G used: 30G (20%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc2
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 34.36GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdb2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 19.9C mobo: N/A gpu: 67.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 263 Uptime: 15 min Memory: 1905.0/15990.7MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.3.0
           Client: Shell (zsh 5.4.2) inxi: 2.3.56
```

I belive my problem originated from this line:

```
May 29 07:18:49 main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1326]: [1857:1878:0529/071849.958728:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(416)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
```

When I search this error, I mostly found Google Chrome bugs but I couldn't find useful fix.

Can anyone help me about this problem.

Edit:

New log lines:

```
May 29 07:43:27 main avahi-daemon[763]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.222.
May 29 07:43:27 main avahi-daemon[763]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 29 07:43:27 main avahi-daemon[763]: Registering new address record for 192.168.2.222 on enp4s0.IPv4.
May 29 07:43:27 main systemd-networkd[356]: enp4s0: Configured
May 29 07:43:29 main systemd-resolved[679]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
May 29 07:43:30 main avahi-daemon[763]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 29 07:43:30 main avahi-daemon[763]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7.
May 29 07:43:30 main avahi-daemon[763]: Registering new address record for fdb3:fcc5:db9:0:d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.*.
May 29 07:43:30 main avahi-daemon[763]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe35:b0e7 on enp4s0.
May 29 07:43:30 main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: [2285:2299:0529/074330.157836:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(416)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -21
May 29 07:43:30 main systemd-resolved[679]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
May 29 07:43:32 main systemd-resolved[679]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
May 29 07:43:34 main systemd-resolved[679]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
May 29 07:43:49 main systemd-resolved[679]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
May 29 07:43:50 main systemd-resolved[679]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
May 29 07:43:52 main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: [2285:2299:0529/074352.174931:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(416)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
May 29 07:43:55 main systemd-resolved[679]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
```

Edit 2:
My Ethernet chip was broken. I try with new Ethernet Card and I can connect perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to **Ask** Ubuntu! What's your question? How exactly is the machine in question connected to the internet? Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

make sure the tcp clinet server in the modem is working right or not

use the network commands and then go and set the ip adress as required or else there is a internet help from google type "my ip adress" and get it and verify it with the use of the system in the use in rel time according to your broadband connectivity.

Comment: I checked my routers and It works perfectly. I change my network cable and problem doesn't solve.